# IC sheaves and formal neighbourhoods

Tags: intersection-cohomology, l-adic-sheaves

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two schemes of finite type over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$. Let $x$ (resp. $y$) be an $\mathbb F_q$-point of $X$ (resp. of $Y$).

Let now $l$ be a prime which is prime to $q$. Let $IC(X), IC(Y)$ denote the corresponding $l$-adic intersection cohomology sheaves.
Assume now that we are given an isomorphism between the formal neighbourhoods of $x$ and $y$.

$\mathbf{Question:}$ Does it give rise to an isomorphism between the stalk of $IC(X)$ at $x$ and the stalk of $IC(Y)$ at $y$ (compatible with the action of Frobenius on both stalks)? In fact, for my purposes it is enough to know that they are abstractly isomorphic (in a way which is compatible with the action of Frobenius).

Comment: By Artin's approximation theorem, if there exists a formal isomorphism between the formal neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$, then there exists a pair of etale morphisms of pointed schemes $f:(Z,z)\to (X,x)$, $g:(Z,z)\to (Y,y)$ such that the induced formal isomorphism $gf^{-1}$ agrees with your formal isomorphism to a specified degree.

Comment: Thus, it suffices to prove that for every etale morphism of pointed schemes $h:(X,x)\to (Y,y)$, there is an isomorphism of stalks.

Comment: Thanks. I think for an etale morphism the statement is obvious.